# can a localIdentifier of a phasset be nil in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, phasset

Im adding PHassets to core data from photo library. And when I fetch the assets from DB, the values of some localIdentifiers is nil(no assets added/removed from photos library). Is it really possible/okay for the localIdentifier of an asset to be nil ?

Comment: I was adding the assets local identifiers to local DB. I was using PHAssets enumeration to iterate through PHAssets of the photo library. Since PHAsset enumeration is a block call and hence is asynchronous. That is why the adding to DB and enumerations were out of sync bcoz of which I was getting nil values in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to have a nil.

Take for example, the user selected an image, video, or live photo inside your app.  They then upload to the iCloud that image and/or delete image locally.  Your app stored the PHAsset's localIdentifier in Realm or CoreData local database and remembered the localIdentifier, however when you go to retrieve the asset from the device it's no longer found (or nil).